# Arduino Compiling Error "Error compiling for board Arduino Nano"

Tags: arduino

I am using an Arduino Nano, DRV8825 driver with a NEMA17 stepper, and 4 buttons to simulate ACS712 current sensors that will be used later. In short each button is attached to analog pins (A0,A1,A2,A3) and the analog ports are coded for specific degrees (0,45,225,270), After some work I was able to get the code to operate as wanted. The stepper response to the buttons and takes the shortest route (CW or CCW) to the next selection regardless of order of selection. If you select the same button twice it remain in current position as it is already there! As this is a work in progress, I am making changes one at a time such as in adding coding to write a digital pin high for a relay and changing over to an array for portions of the code. That’s where I am getting the Error compiling for board Arduino Nano. I going to include 2 codes, one working and one that give the compile ERROR.  I hope I have not violated any rules and have read some results that didn’t seem to apply.

enter code here

```
                         //THIS ONE GIVE THE ABOVE ERROR//

  //same as 1.0 but names changed to na=new angle & CA=current angle // This one seem to work, had 
    change some code to get it to work in all examples. // Using buttons to simulate analog inputs 
    for now. // Adding led to represent vac relay on/off PIN 4

    // defines pins numbers const int stepPin = 3; const int dirPin = 2; const int enPin = 8; const 
    int vacPin = 4; //Just added this for vac

// Button asignments //const int b1 = A0; //const int b2 = A1; //const int b3 = A2; //const int b4 = A3;

const int PIN_COUNT = 4; int inputPins[PIN_COUNT] = {A0, A1, A2, A3}; int outputVals[4] = {0, 45, 225, 270};

int ca = 0; //currentAngle int na = 0; //angle int stepPerAngle = 5 / 9; // full step = 1.8 or could have used "*1.8" int numstep;

void setup() { Serial.begin(9600); for (int index = 0; index < 4; index++) // Sets the 3 pins as Outputs pinMode(stepPin, OUTPUT); pinMode(dirPin, OUTPUT); pinMode(enPin, OUTPUT); pinMode(vacPin, OUTPUT); //Just added this for vac

//set values for 2 outputs digitalWrite(enPin, LOW); digitalWrite(dirPin, HIGH); digitalWrite(vacPin, LOW); //just add this for vac

// set buttons as inputs, some of these will become inputs from ACS712's /* pinMode(A0, INPUT); pinMode(A1, INPUT); pinMode(A2, INPUT); pinMode(A3, INPUT); }*/

void loop(); int n; for (int index = 0; index < 4; index++)

/* int n;
  // Assign button degrees
  if      ( digitalRead(A0) == HIGH) {
   na = 0;
  }
  else if ( digitalRead(A1) == HIGH) {
   na = 45;
  }
  else if ( digitalRead(A2) == HIGH) {
   na = 225;
  }
  else if ( digitalRead(A3) == HIGH) {
   na = 270;
  }*/

//currentAngle=ca    new angle=na
// 1st SCENARIO if these to ARE the same nothing happens
//only if they ARE not equal then steps through to find a true statement to act ohn
//if (ca = na) {digitalWrite(vacPin, HIGH);}
if ( ca != na ) {
  //  Serial.println (ca);
  //2nd SCENARIO
  if (na - ca > 0 && na - ca <= 180)
  { digitalWrite(dirPin, HIGH);
    n = ((na - ca) * 5 / 9);
    numstep = n;
    ca = na;
  }

  //3rd SCENARIO
  else if (ca - na > 0 && ca - na > 180)
  { digitalWrite(dirPin, HIGH);
    n = ((na + 360 - ca) * 5 / 9);
    numstep = n;
    ca = na;
  }

  // 4th SCENARIO
  else if (na - ca < 0 && na - ca <= 180)
  { digitalWrite(dirPin, LOW);
    n = ((ca - na) * 5 / 9);
    numstep = n;
    ca = na; (ca);
  }

  //5th SCENARIO
  else if (na - ca > 0 && na - ca > 180)
  { digitalWrite(dirPin, LOW);
    n = ((ca + 360 - na) * 5 / 9);
    numstep = n;
    ca = na; (ca);
  }

  for (int x = 0; x < numstep; x++) {

    digitalWrite(stepPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(1000);  //speed
    digitalWrite(stepPin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(1000);
  }  //speed
  delay(500);
}
}
                     //THIS ONE COMPILES WITH NO ERRORS//
 //same as 1.0 but names changed to na=new angle & CA=current angle // This one seem to work, had change some code to get it to work in all examples. // Using buttons to simulate analog inputs for now. // Adding led to represent vac relay on/off PIN 4

// defines pins numbers const int stepPin = 3; const int dirPin = 2; const int enPin = 8; const int vacPin = 4; //Just added this for vac

// Button asignment //const int b1 = A0; //const int b2 = A1; //const int b3 = A2; //const int b4 = A3;

int ca = 0; //currentAngle int na = 0; //angle int stepPerAngle = 5 / 9; // full step = 1.8 or could have used "*1.8" int numstep;

void setup() { Serial.begin(9600);

// Sets the 3 pins as Outputs pinMode(stepPin, OUTPUT); pinMode(dirPin, OUTPUT); pinMode(enPin, OUTPUT); pinMode(vacPin, OUTPUT); //Just added this for vac

//set values for 2 outputs digitalWrite(enPin, LOW); digitalWrite(dirPin, HIGH); digitalWrite(vacPin, LOW); //just add this for vac

// set buttons as inputs, some of these will become inputs from ACS712's pinMode(A0, INPUT); pinMode(A1, INPUT); pinMode(A2, INPUT); pinMode(A3, INPUT); }

void loop() { int n; // Assign button degrees if ( digitalRead(A0) == HIGH) { na = 0; } else if ( digitalRead(A1) == HIGH) { na = 45; } else if ( digitalRead(A2) == HIGH) { na = 225; } else if ( digitalRead(A3) == HIGH) { na = 270; }

//currentAngle=ca new angle=na // 1st SCENARIO if these to ARE the same nothing happens //only if they ARE not equal then steps through to find a true statement to act ohn //if (ca = na) {digitalWrite(vacPin, HIGH);} if ( ca != na ) { // Serial.println (ca); //2nd SCENARIO if (na - ca > 0 && na - ca <= 180) { digitalWrite(dirPin, HIGH); n = ((na - ca) * 5 / 9); numstep = n; ca = na; }

//3rd SCENARIO
else if (ca - na > 0 && ca - na > 180)
{ digitalWrite(dirPin, HIGH);
  n = ((na + 360 - ca) * 5 / 9);
  numstep = n;
  ca = na;
}

// 4th SCENARIO
else if (na - ca < 0 && na - ca <= 180)
{ digitalWrite(dirPin, LOW);
  n = ((ca - na) * 5 / 9);
  numstep = n;
  ca = na; (ca);
}

//5th SCENARIO
else if (na - ca > 0 && na - ca > 180)
{ digitalWrite(dirPin, LOW);
  n = ((ca + 360 - na) * 5 / 9);
  numstep = n;
  ca = na; (ca);
}

for (int x = 0; x < numstep; x++) {

  digitalWrite(stepPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(1000);  //speed
  digitalWrite(stepPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(1000);
}  //speed
delay(500);
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

“Error compiling for board Arduino Nano”

Is just the end of the error message. The actual error message with the information what is wrong is above that.

I won't go too much into detail here because your code is so badly formatted that I can't simply copy paste it. If you want other people's help the least you can do is post your code with line breaks. You cannot have comments and code in the same line.

The first thing that would jump into my eye is this:

```
void loop(); int n; for (int index = 0; index < 4; index++)
```

If you would compare the code that works vs the code that does not compile you would find out a few important differences.

For example that you have a semicolon where you need `{`.

```
void loop () {
  // you code
}
```

Now scroll the console up, find out what the compiler is complaining about and fix that. You can find solutions to any error message online if you leave out your variable names and search for the common text.

Comment: Note that you left out the parentheses in void loop

Comment: Sorry about that. I scrolled up to see the example you were pointing out and something didn't paste right.  Not all the code was there and was very confusing.  I had it ready to post and it disappeared, I hurried to redo it and obviously mess it up.. Will try again later after I am more rested.